# I am having an issue with consistency in jumping

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I've set up a pretty basic platformer game, & I am getting it all set up right now.

Everything works perfect other than the jumping, I am getting very inconsistent jump lengths. They range from very short to very long.

I am not used to working with Slick2D, JWJGL, or the delta integer, please help!

Here is my whole code for the level:

```java
package game;

import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class LevelOne extends BasicGameState{

    Animation walkingLeft, walkingRight, still;
    int[] duration = {200,200,200};

    Image p;
    Image map;

    public String mouse = "Mouse not detected";
    public String gpos = "null";
    public int health = 1000;
    float CharX = 0;
    float CharY = 0;
    float PosX = CharX + 100;
    float PosY = CharY + 300;
    boolean jumping = false; 
    float verticalSpeed = 0.0f;


    public LevelOne(int state){

    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)throws SlickException{
        p = new Image("res/char.png");
        map = new Image("res/map.png");


        Image[] Left = {p.getSubImage(0,32,32,32), p.getSubImage(32,32,32,32), p.getSubImage(64,32,32,32)};
        Image[] Right = {p.getSubImage(0,64,32,32), p.getSubImage(0,64,32,32), p.getSubImage(0,64,32,32)};


        walkingLeft = new Animation(Left, duration, false);
        walkingRight = new Animation(Right, duration, false);
        still = walkingLeft;
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)throws SlickException{
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.drawString("Developers Build", 650, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(mouse, 650, 150);
        g.drawString(gpos,650, 200);                   //Developers Build Sidebar thing
        g.drawString("Class: ", 650, 250);
        g.drawString("" + this.getClass(), 670, 270);
        g.drawString("State: " + this.getID(), 650, 300);
        g.drawString("Stage: Charlie", 650, 350);
        g.drawRect(620, 70, 400, 320);


        map.draw(CharX, CharY);                 //Floor



        g.setColor(Color.white);
        if(health < 500){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        }
        g.drawString("Health: " + health, 10, 50);  
        g.setColor(Color.white);                                                //Health & Level
        g.drawString("Level: 1", 10, 70);


        still.draw(PosX, PosY);                       //Draw Character





    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
        Input input = gc.getInput();

        int MouseX = Mouse.getX();
        int MouseY = Mouse.getY();
        mouse = "JPos: " + MouseX + " , " + MouseY;
        gpos = "GPos: " + MouseX + " , " + (460 - MouseY);


        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D)){
            still = walkingRight;
            CharX -= delta * .2f;
        }

        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)){
            still = walkingLeft;
            CharX += delta * .2f;
            if(CharX > 100){
                CharX -= delta *.2f;
            }
        }

        if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_W) && !jumping) { 
            verticalSpeed = -1f * delta;//negative value indicates an upward movement 
            jumping = true;
       }

       if (jumping) { 
            verticalSpeed += .0099f * delta;//change this value to alter gravity strength          
       }

       if(PosY > 300){         
           jumping = false;
           verticalSpeed = 0;          
           PosY = 300;
       }

       PosY += verticalSpeed;



        if(health == 0){
            CharX = 0;
            health = 1000;
        }


    }

    public int getID(){
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If delta is some kind of "time elapsed" value, then you shouldn't be multiplying with it. A jump speed is independent from your framerate. Just choose a good speed speed:

```
if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_W) && !jumping)
{
    verticalSpeed = -1.0f;
    jumping = true;
}
```

Play a bit around with the value.

Comment: My answer is probably what you really want. This will not handle changes in frame rate well.  Your game will run slower or faster on different PCs if FPS isn't used to scale velocity.

Comment: Nope, you don't understand the idea of velocity. A velocity should be used by integrating it over time from 0 to the time step (which is the delta right here). This simply gives that the amount of motion, at velocity v equals delta * v. So that is what you have to add each frame to your position: position += velocity * step.

Comment: Nope, you failed to understand me. Lets review some simple algebra.(v1+v2)×step = v1×step+v2×step. The latter equation is how my solution would work. However I do submit that the former approach (which you suggest) is more efficient and less prone to floating point error. As you do not mention scaling by time, I feel your answer needs improving.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale your jump velocity by delta.  Right now you're just negating delta, which means your jump power is equal to elapsed time between frames per millisecond.  That's too variable.

Your code should really read something like:

```
float JUMP_POWER = .1f;
if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_W) && !jumping){
    verticalSpeed = -delta*JUMP_POWER;
}
```

This would mean your character has vertical velocity of .1 pixels per millisecond when jumping.  If delta is in milliseconds :) not sure if it is.  If you don't see the character moving position, just increase jump power.

You do this because every action needs to be scaled by time.  Is how simple physics works in real life.  Velocity alters position over time.  So to simulate this, you need to calculate velocity relative to time between timesteps.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually missing one final piece of the puzzle, if you think back to physics class, change in position with constant acceleration is actually:

d = (v * t) + (1/2 * a * t^2)

Where
d is the distance
v is velocity
t is time
a is acceleration

Something like...

```
if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_W) && !jumping) { 
        verticalSpeed = JUMP_POWER;
        jumping = true;
}
PosY = PosY + (verticalSpeed * deltaTime) + (0.5f * gravity * deltaTime * deltaTime);
verticalSpeed = gravity * deltaTime;
```

So not only will you need to multiple the velocity by time, but to make the game run the same on any FPS, you'll also need to add 1/2 * a * t^2 to calculate the correct distance.